# django: can we do loader.get_template('my_template.txt')?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to use django template to process plain text file, and tried this:

```
from django.template import loader, Context
t = loader.get_template('my_template.txt')
```

however, it works for this:

```
from django.template import loader, Context
t = loader.get_template('my_template.html')
```

Can we load txt files using django template loader? how?

thanks.

Comment: Can't help but ask the obvious question: Does `my_template.txt` exist? Django's template engine doesn't care if you're using text, html, xml, or anything else, so long as it's a text file.

Comment: yes. it does.  i put both in the same directory.

Comment: Are you doubly sure? It has to be in one a TEMPLATE_DIRS dir defined in settings. That's the only thing I can think of, otherwise it should be able to open any text file. Try copying your html file to .txt, perhaps the .txt you're working with isn't the right mimetype if it was created strangely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Seth commented I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work. Django doesn't care about the extension of the file. You can very well load `my_template.foo`.

Check the following:

1. The file is indeed present where it should be. If it is in a subdirectory then you'll have to use `loader.get_template('<subdirectory>/my_template.txt')` where subdirectory is the name of the directory.
2. Check if you have an app name. It is common to locate all templates for an app in a directory with the app's name.
3. As @Seth said double check your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting. The template should be inside one the directories in this list.

Answer (score -7):

I would leave this for some one else to answer as I am not very comfortable with Django.

How ever, if you are interested in templates and plain text processing, why don't you look at slew of other products available within python.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98245/what-is-your-single-favorite-python-templating-engine
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating