# Django passing JSON data to static getJSON/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, mysql, django

I am trying to grab data from my models.py and serialize it into a JSON object within my views.py.

**Models.py:**

```
class Platform(models.Model):
     platformtype = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

**Views.py:**

```
def startpage(request):
   return render_to_response('Main.html');


def index(request):
   platforms_as_json = serializers.serialize('json', Platform.objects.all())
   return HttpResponse(platforms_as_json, content_type='json')
```

After doing this I want to pass this object into my static javascript file which is using getJSON to populate my drop down list for my template(Main.html).

**JavaScript:**

```
$.getJSON("{{platforms_as_json}}", function (data) {
 $.each(data, function (index, item) {
     $('#platformList').append(
          $('<option></option>').val(item).html(item.platformtype)
);
 });
});
```

I have looked at many other threads within SO, but all of them are for those using embedded JS within their template and/or not using getJSON. As of right now, data is not being displayed in the list when I run my Django development server. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

{% load static from staticfiles %}
<script type = 'text/javascript' >

var platformsjson = "({% autoescape off %}{{platforms_as_json}}{% endautoescape %})";

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id = "platformList"></select>

<ul id = "root"></ul>
<div id = "root"></div>
<script src = "{% static 'admin/js/platformddown_script.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**platformddown_script.js:**

```
$.each(platformsjson, function (index, item) {
   $('#platformList').append(
           $('<option></option>').val(item.platformtype).html(item.platformtype)
   )
   });
```

After this update it still doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at DRF (ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main html render + json data

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render

def startpage(request):
    platforms = Platform.objects.select_related().values('platformtype')
    return render(request, 'Main.html', {'platforms_as_json': json.dumps(list(platforms)),})
```

in template

```
{{ platforms_as_json }}
```

html and js

```
<select id="platformList"></select>

<script>
    $.each({% autoescape off %}{{platforms_as_json}}{% endautoescape %}, function (index, item) {
        $('#platformList').append(
                $('<option></option>').val(item.platformtype).html(item.platformtype)
        )
    });
</script>
```

Old example
https://gist.github.com/leotop/014a38bd97407a6380f2526f11d17977

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to grab directly from a JSON file. Maybe I shouldn't be using getJSON, but I want to grab JSON objects from Django. To be able to take data from models.py and make those into JSON objects. Is that possible?

Comment: how render main template? from django.shortcuts import render. HttpResponse not render template.

Comment: In URL patterns I have:   url(r'^$', Main).

Comment: Importing this.....from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

Comment: why would I need <script src="/json/geo.json"></script> ? I don't have a json file. I see the update you made, where in the template do I place {{ platforms_json }}?

Comment: <script type = "text/javascript">
var platforms_as_json = {{platforms_as_json}};
</script> like this in my html template?

Comment: I see. this is what I get -> [{
 "platformtype": "platformA"
}, {
 "platformtype": "platformB"
}, {
 "platformtype": "platformC"
}, {
 "platformtype": "platformD"
}] but not within the drop down list box

Comment: https://gist.github.com/leotop/4cee0bc9e37e4ba76da3f3f426460afc - Main.html full example

Comment: I tried to do something like that it still doesn't display the data within the drop down list. I followed your code as well, still doesn't work. I'm so confused as to why it is working :( Although your javascript is within your html, mine is a separate javascript file. Although that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: full work example in archive. {% autoescape off %}{{platforms_as_json}}{% endautoescape %}. Default django escape code. If need use as variable. var platform = {% autoescape off %}{{platforms_as_json}}{% endautoescape %}; getJSON unnecessary, variable already json.

Comment: When I have it within my html template it works, but when I put it in a separate javascript file it doesn't work.

Comment: Could this be because we are rending json and html together in views? So that's why I can't implement this solution within a separate static javascript file?

Comment: yes. js file is static. Need generate js or dynamic. Generate write json to file. Dynamic - urls.py route ^file.js in views render by template.

Comment: I would like my javascript files to be static while being able to pass in the platforms_as_json. Is that possible? How would I pass platforms_as_json into my static javascript file?

Comment: render as template and save to file. from django.template.loader import get_template http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817926/django-can-we-do-loader-get-templatemy-template-txt

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to do <script> var platformsjson = "{% autoescape off %}{{platforms_as_json}}{% endautoescape %}"; </script> in template/html then in javascript                                                           $.each(platformsjson, function (index, item) {
       $('#platformList').append(
               $('<option></option>').val(item.platformtype).html(item.platformtype)
       )
   });

Comment: I did not understand the question. {% %} and {{ }} django template tags, use render to view, js values global in page.

Comment: In HTML/Template I put <script> var platformsjson = "{% autoescape off %}{{platforms_as_json}}{% endautoescape %}"; </script>      and in static javascript file I put             $.each(platformsjson, function (index, item) { $('#platformList').append( $('<option></option>').val(item.platformtype).html(item.platformtype) ) });

Comment: html up var platformsjson, html <script src=""> bottom to body

Comment: var platformsjson = "({% autoescape
my code var platformsjson = {% autoescape not bracket and quote

Comment: wow, I thought I tried that and failed. But this time it worked. Thank you so much for all of your time and effort! I really appreciate it :)